# Get value from jQuery Datarow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have an asp.net page - I am using jQuery datatables on it.

Part of the code is below:

```
                        <% foreach (SubmissionSearchResult result in SearchResults)
                           {%>
                        <tr data-name='<%=result.ID %>'>
```

So each time a row is drew on screen I am adding a data-name of result ID to it.  What I want then is on clicking the row retrieve this ID.

I had something like the below to start :

```
        $('#searchResultsTbl').on("click", "tbody tr", function () {
            var nTds = $('td', this);

            var id = $(nTds[0]).text().trim();
```

This worked when the id was in the first td in the row but now the columns can be dynammic and it may not be in the first column.  So I wanted to add the id to each row and then get it from the row so I added it as a data-name but not sure on how to get the value back from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            $('#searchResultsTbl').on("click", "tbody tr", function () {
                var id = $(this).data('name');
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $('#searchResultsTbl tr:gt(0)').click(function () {
        var this_row = $(this);
        var data_name = this_row.attr('data-name');//row attribute
        var first_td = $.trim(this_row.find('td:eq(0)').html());
        var second_td = $.trim(this_row.find('td:eq(1)').html());
        var third_td = $.trim(this_row.find('td:eq(2)').html());//and so on
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

add the javascript function on click event of row

like

```
       <tr data-name='<%=result.ID %>' onclick='showid("<%=result.ID %>")'>
```

Now in javascript define this showid function

```
        function showid(rowvalue)
         {
               alert(rowvalue);
          }
```